# How to change some the values of a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension

I have the following list of tuples:

```
lis = [('The', 'DET'),
 ('iphone', 'X'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('a', 'DET'),
 ('very', 'ADV'),
 ('nice', 'ADJ'),
 ('device', 'NOUN'),
 ('.', 'PUNCT'),
 ('However', 'ADP'),
 ('the', 'DET'),
 ('pixel', 'X'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('by', 'ADP'),
 ('far', 'ADV'),
 ('more', 'ADV'),
 ('interesting', 'ADJ'),
 ('since', 'ADV'),
 ('it', 'PRON'),
 ('was', 'AUX'),
 ('made', 'VERB'),
 ('by', 'ADP'),
 ('google', 'NOUN'),
 ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

My main objective is to specifically change the values of the this tuples: `('iphone', 'X'), ('pixel', 'X'), ('google', 'NOUN')` to `('iphone', 'device'), ('pixel', 'device'), ('google', 'entity')`. Thus, since I am interested in preserve the order, I tried the following:

```
tags['Google'] = 'device'
tags['pixel'] = 'device'
tags['iphone'] = 'entity'
#this one is not present in lis . Nevertheless, I would like to add it just in case I need it.
tags['galaxy'] = 'device'
tags = list(tags.items())
tags = OrderedDict(postag(str(sample)))
```

Since I added `tags['galaxy'] = 'device'` it is actually adding it at the end of the list as `('galaxy', 'device')`. Therefore, my question is how can I fix and update the values of for tuples if they exist?.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a list of tuples? Tuples are immutable so by design I wouldn't use them if I knew they may/would be changed. For example, perhaps you can use a dictionary to store the mappings, and maybe a separate list to keep the order of the keys?

Comment: @MxyL Unfortunatly yes, tuples are necessary... I also figure out what your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to rebuild the list

```
tags = {'google': 'entity', 'iphone': 'device', ...}

lis = [(a, tags[a.lower()]) if a.lower() in tags else (a, b) for a, b in lis]
```

This will overwrite tuples like `('iphone', 'something')`, that is to say it doesn't care what's in the second variable.

Comment: What about if they do not exist in my text?. Do comprehension lists are enough robust to deal with this and not adding them?.

Comment: This list comprehension will not put values in `lis` that are not already there.  Some reading on list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: You have something in your `lis` that is not an `(a, b)` 2-ple

Comment: Sorry I confused some names. This one worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change this is place and already have the values you need to replace them with, I'd simply create a dictionary out of the replacement fields and then replace:

```
rep = dict([('iphone', 'device'), ('pixel', 'device'), ('google', 'entity')])

for ind, (i, j) in enumerate(lis):
    if i in rep:
        lis[ind] = (i, rep[i])
```